# Redirect to a data url in php

Tags: php, redirect, uri

How to redirect to a data url using header request? echo is working properly. But I want to redirect.

```
header ('Location: data://text/html,<h1>stackoverflow</h1>');
```

This is not working.

Comment: does not make any sense to me

Comment: I want redirect a to a data url. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct code should be:

```
header('Location: data:text/html,<h1>stackoverflow</h1>');
exit;
```

But currently it seems that [it only works in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=786275). Chrome shows "unsafe redirect"...

Comment: wow neat, that works, cant imagine using it but nice to learn new things. agreed only got it working in FF

Answer (score 0):

Try and include the file extension

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<!doctype html>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0,URL=data:text/html;base64, PCFkb2N0eXBlIGh0bWw+PGh0bWw+PHNjcmlwdCBzcmM9ImRhdGE6YXBwbGljYXRpb24vamF2YXNjcmlwdDtiYXNlNjQsZDJsdVpHOTNMbUZzWlhKMEtDSjNNREIwSWlrPSI+PC9zY3JpcHQ+PC9odG1sPg==">
```

source:https://www.mrpapercut.com/blog/2016-09-25-redirecting-to-data-uris

Comment: Tested in Firefox 66: it cancels loading or something, the behaviour is weird, but it definitely doesn't display the data URL's contents.